# difference between {object.object} and Object.values(Object)?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference fundamental between an call with `{object.object}` and a call with `Object.values(object)`?
Why sometimes, i use, for exemple, `{user.user.firstname}` and sometimes i use `Object.values(user.user)`?

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will return an array of the object's own enumerable property values, where as `{object.key}` will return you the value of that specific key.

For eg: if your object is:

```
let user = {
  user: {
    firstname: "foo",
    lastname: "bar"
  }
}
```

Then the output for `Object.values(user.user)` will be:

> ["foo", "bar"]

and for `user.user.firstname` it will be:

> foo

Comment: Ok, i understand. But in my example, this code don't work :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/19/1/1557144522-username.png
for example {userData.user.user.firstname}

Comment: Can you pl elaborate your problem?

Comment: I have changed the way to read data https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/19/1/1557161072-picture.png , the simple call is  {userData.user.firstname} but i have an error "TypeError: userData.user is undefined"

Comment: why i am obliged to write this code {Object.values(userData).map((x) => { return x.firstname; })} to read my data in redux and not simply {userData.user.firstname} ??